# With PHP substr, how can I find the previous whitespace instead of the following whitespace?

Tags: php, string, whitespace

I would like to crop off a string at the whitespace **before** the word which is cut off. Currently I have working code for cropping off a string at the whitespace **after** the word which is cut off, but this exceeds my max char limit.

I did some experimenting and I was able to find a solution to find the whitespace, so that instead of cropping off the middle of a word, strpos will instead find the whitespace after the word which falls within the character limit and then crop the string.

```
$thestring = "my really really really really really really really";
$getlength = strlen($thestring);
$maxLength = 42;

if ($getlength > $maxLength) { 
    echo substr($thestring, 0, strpos($thestring, ' ', $maxLength));
    echo "...";
} else {
    echo $thestring;
}
echo " - long string";
```

This is fully working, the only thing, is that I want to put a hard limit to the number of characters in the string. But what this does is crop after the word it falls between, which puts it a few characters over the limit.

For example, this will return this string:

```
my really really really really really really - long string
```

because 42 characters falls on the last "really", so it extends the length to the next whitespace. But now the returned string is 44 characters.

What I would rather like it to do, is that since the exact 42 characters returns:

```
my really really really really really real
```

then, instead, I would like to crop it to the **prior** whitespace, not the following whitespace. So like in this example, I would like this returned:

```
my really really really really really - long string
```

This is good, because it crops off the last partial word, so instead of returning just part of the last word `real` which looks bad, or *after* the whole word `really` which exceeds my max character limit, then instead it crops the partial last word causing the total string to fall below the max limit, which is what I want.

So like my desired returned string above would be 37 characters, which is what I want because it's less than 42.

So, how can I modify my code to crop it at the prior whitespace to the word which the end of the maxLength falls on, rather than the following whitespace?

Comment: based on your source, you can try to use: `substr($thestring,0,strrpos($thestring,' ',$maxLength-$getlength));`

Comment: ooh looks good, lemme try :) edit: nope,. still gets the following whitespace not the prior whitespace.

Comment: are you use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strrpos.php) instead of [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) ? my test code is : `php -r '$s="my really really really really really really"; echo substr($s,0,strrpos($s," ",42-strlen($s)));'`

Comment: [it's command line .. just for test from terminal](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

Comment: no i'm using strpos. edit: your code above, which translates to `echo substr($thestring, 0, strrpos($thestring, " ", $maxLength-strlen($thestring)));`, doesn't work, it only does the same thing my code already does - it strips after the cutoff word, not before it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I don't know why my sample of code didn't work for you (it's really strange) :-/

But this is the full code based on your source:

```
<?php
$thestring = "my really really really really really really really";
$getlength = strlen($thestring);
$maxLength = 42;

if ($getlength > $maxLength) {
    echo substr($thestring, 0, strrpos($thestring, ' ', $maxLength-$getlength));
    echo "...";
} else {
    echo $thestring;
}
echo " - long string";
```

for my console it outputs:

```
   [64] $ php ./ex.php
   my really really really really really... - long string
```

Comment: you're right, I just tested that copy and pasted, maybe there is another issue with my site.. let me experiment

Comment: oh i figured out what happened. it was actually a problem with what I was looking at. to understand where i went wrong, my char limit is 83 characters. in notepad++, i copied the string to see how many characters there were. at the bottom of the screen in notepad++, there are two sections, length: and lines:, and then next to that, Ln: and Col:. Well with an 83 character string, notepadd ++ shows this info: `length: 83 lines: 1` `Ln: 1 Col: 84`. You see that 84? Well I was looking at that number thinking it was 1 character too long.

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Not good way to make it, but at least it can work.

1. You have your $strlen = 42
2. Slice this string to match $strlen
3. Explode new string by space
4. Print out all array values exept last one.

**EDIT:**

This is the code, actually I'm not very happy about it but it works at least.

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
$strLength = 42;
$strCut = substr($str, 0, $strLength);
$strExp = explode(" ", $strCut);

$newTxtSize = count($strExp) - 2;

$output = "";
for($i = 0; $i <= $newTxtSize; $i++){
    $output .= $strExp[$i] .' ';
}

echo rtrim($output,  " ") . "...";
```

Comment: sounds interesting, can you show an example of this?

Comment: yours might work but please provide an example so i can try it. It would make sense that maybe by exploding the whitespace you can choose the whitespace you want, but I'm just guessing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use strpos and substr try this code:

```
$content = "my really really really really really really really";

$pos=strpos($content, ' ', 20);
$new = substr($content,0,$pos );

$fromfirstwhitespace = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $new);

echo ($fromfirstwhitespace);
```

cheers!!!

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I think this only does what I already did.

Comment: are you joking you asked to select the caracther and cut from the first white space so copy and past this code

Comment: $content = "my really really really really really really really";

$pos=strpos($content, ' ', 20);
$new = substr($content,0,$pos );

echo ($new);

Comment: I just tried your comment code and it didn't work, did the same thing as I already did.

Comment: Sorry for lost your 'before' try this

Comment: $content = "my really really really really really really really";

$pos=strpos($content, ' ', 20);
$new = substr($content,0,$pos );

$fromfirstwhitespace = preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '$1', $new);

echo ($fromfirstwhitespace);

Comment: already have a working one but i upvoted for your effort (someone else had downvoted your previous answer before you edited).

Comment: Ok thanks, anyway check if you like I think it's cleaned solution.

Answer (score 0):

a short function to cut by default, not cut, or cut to the first space found next after the number of chars wanted ...

```
function cut_string($nb_chars, $str){
      
      // define a nb chart by defaut
      $nb_chars_default = 250;
      
      // use default or number wanted
      $nb_chars = ( $nb_chars != 0
      || $nb_chars != '' ) ? $nb_chars : $nb_chars_default;
      
      // size of the string in nb chars
      $len_str = strlen($str);

      // if the string is too long
      if( $len_str > $nb_chars ){
        
        // cut string just at the first space after nb chars wanted
        return substr( $str, 0, strrpos($str, ' ', $nb_chars-$len_str) );
      }
      else{

        return $str;
      }
}

// use :
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";

$my_cut_string = cut_string(200, $str);

echo $my_cut_string;

// output :
// Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
```